# File encryption/decryption on Android SD card

Tags: android, file, encryption, sd-card

I want to encrypt/decrypt a file on sd card so that no one can access that file on android. Is there any possibility to do that? Any code?

Comment: this is most problem for android developer sometime much resource are include in our project and apk size would be limited so we like do download sd card and show but raise problem of security

Comment: Yes Nik i am facing same problem because of limited internal memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can [easily encrypt file](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.crypto/DesFile.html) on Android, but you need a key to encrypt data.

Where will you store that key? Inside apk? Capable engineers will be able to reverse-engineer your apk and extract the key.

The only secure option is to require user to enter password, which you use to hash the key. This will prevent 3rd parties (= stolen phone) to get to the file, but it will not prevent owners of the phone access to the file (i.e. DRM not possible).